# Chat bot using google app engine is not replying

Tags: java, eclipse, google-app-engine

heres the code
it basically takes a message and echos it back.
the problem is it is not replying at all :( 
in google app engine, my applications page, i get error-"The requested URL /guestbook was not found on this server."

```
package guestbook;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

import javax.servlet.http.*;
import com.google.appengine.api.xmpp.JID;
import com.google.appengine.api.xmpp.Message;
import com.google.appengine.api.xmpp.MessageBuilder;
import com.google.appengine.api.xmpp.XMPPService;
import com.google.appengine.api.xmpp.XMPPServiceFactory;






@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class GuestbookServlet extends HttpServlet {

private static final Logger LOG = 
          Logger.getLogger(GuestbookServlet.class.getName());

public void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
        throws IOException {

       // Parse incoming message
    XMPPService xmpp = XMPPServiceFactory.getXMPPService();
    Message msg = xmpp.parseMessage(req);
    JID jid = msg.getFromJid();
    String body = msg.getBody();
    LOG.info(jid.getId() + " --> JEliza: " + body);

    // Get a response from Eliza
    String response = "echo: " + body;
    LOG.info(jid.getId() + " <-- JEliza: " + response);

    // Send out response
    msg = new MessageBuilder()
        .withRecipientJids(jid)
        .withBody(response)
        .build();
    xmpp.sendMessage(msg);

    /*Message message = xmpp.parseMessage(req);
    JID fromJid = message.getFromJid();
    String body = message.getBody();

    String respMsg = null;

    if (body.equals("/list")) {
        respMsg = "Hi";
      } else if (body.equals("/help")) {
        respMsg = "Welcome to the Guestbook Chatbot!\nThe following commands are supported: \n /list \n /help";
      } else {
        respMsg = "Command '" + body + "' not supported! \nEnter '/help' for list of commands.";
      }

    JID tojid = new JID(fromJid.getId());

    Message msg = new MessageBuilder().withRecipientJids(tojid).withBody(respMsg).build();

    boolean messageSent = false;
    xmpp = XMPPServiceFactory.getXMPPService();
    if (xmpp.getPresence(tojid).isAvailable()) {
      SendResponse status = xmpp.sendMessage(msg);
      messageSent = (status.getStatusMap().get(tojid) == SendResponse.Status.SUCCESS);
    }*/

  }



}
```

Answer (score 1):

As per the details you have given i think the problem should be with the web.xml file

```
<servlet><servlet-name>GuestbookServlet</servlet-name><servlet-class>your.package.structure.GuestbookServlet</servlet-class></servlet><servlet-mapping><servlet-name>GuestbookServlet</servlet-name><url-pattern>/_ah/xmpp/message/chat/</url-pattern></servlet-mapping>
```

try adding this into the web.xml change your.package.structure.GuestbookServlet accordingly for example mine would be com.appengine.capp

Comment: thanks for such an early reply.still not working. 
this is my web.xml.
Error: Not Found

The requested URL /guestbook was not found on this server.

this is the error that i get.

    <servlet>
  <servlet-name>GuestbookServlet</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>guestbook.GuestbookServlet</servlet-       class>
 </servlet>
 <servlet-mapping>
   <servlet-name>GuestbookServlet</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/_ah/xmpp/message/chat/</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>

Comment: hope u can understand, i am not able to post it properly

Comment: did you create the project by editing the guestbook example there might be something you missed to change that was already in the example. sorry but that's all i can say. pls take a look at that

Answer (score 0):

JDK settings had to be changed from 1.7 to 1.6.
under window-> preferences -> java -> compiler